# Free variables in a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the linear system $Ax=b$ where
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
 0 &  1 &  1 &  0 \\
 1 &  0 &  0 &  1 \\
 0 &  1 &  0 &  1
\end{bmatrix} .
$$

Let us assume that $b$ is in the column space of $A$.  By elimination
we obtain the $A$ matrix in "echelon" form
$$
\text{ef}(A)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This tells us that $x_4$ is a free variable.  However if we let
$x=(x_1, x_3, x_4, x_2)^\top$ and rearrange the columns
of $A$ accordingly, now
$$
A_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  1 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 &  1 &  0 &  1 \\
 1 &  0 &  1 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 &  1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
doing elimination
$$
\text{ef}(A_2)=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and now $x_2$ is the free variable.

Does that mean that the free variables can be chosen freely?  In this
case it looks like they can be, but does that always work in general?

Comment: Well, yes: you can generally speaking change the free variables at will. Some authors usually choose *the last* variables as the free ones, but that is **not** a must.

Comment: Note that, either way, it's the 4th component of $x$ that gets to be the free variable.